# How to capture a signal from user input?

Tags: linux, signals

I am trying to write a program to ask the user to enter the signal Number and then it will call a handler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void decide(int signo)
{
    printf("I received signal\n");

}

int main()
{
    int signum;

    printf("Enter Signal Number:");
    scanf("%d", &signum);

    if(signal(signum,decide) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror("signal");
    }

    //pause();

    printf("I hope you have a good evening!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

But it seems to skip the signal handler and always print the last line. What can I change so it calls the handler?

Comment: All I can guess is you just define a signal handler. After that use raise(signum);

Answer (score 2):

The [`signal` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) (possibly in contrast to its name) merely sets the signal-handling behaviour for any *future* signals that arise:

> The `signal()` function chooses one of three ways in which receipt of the signal number *sig* **is to be subsequently handled**. If the value of *func* is SIG_DFL, default handling for that signal shall occur. If the value of *func* is SIG_IGN, the signal shall be ignored. Otherwise, the application shall ensure that *func* points to a function to be called when that signal occurs.

Your program sets up a signal handler and checks that there was no error - great! - but then proceeds to print a farewell and exit immediately afterwards, at which point the whole process, including its signal handlers, ceases to exist.

*Setting* a signal handler is a different event in the Unix model to *receiving and handling* a signal. Once you've set the handler, any future signals that arrive will be sent to that handler to deal with and the rest of the program keeps running. If no matching signal ever comes, the handler sits there quietly and never has to do anything.

---

There *is* a very tiny window in which you could deliver a signal before it exits. That window is essentially where your [`pause()` call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html) is commented out - in fact, that's almost exactly what [the purpose of the `pause` function is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html):

> The `pause()` function shall suspend the calling thread until delivery of a signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process.

Either during the `pause` or the microscopic window otherwise, you could `kill -XYZ $pid` from another terminal and your handler would be run. Here's a session where I did that:

```
mwh:/tmp$ ./test
Enter Signal Number:12
I received signal
I hope you have a good evening!
mwh:/tmp$
```

In the other terminal, I found out the PID of my `test` process from `ps awx` and then ran `kill -12 9245`. Before I pressed enter on the `kill`, the `test` process was just sitting there doing nothing, and once I did the signal handler kicked into action, the message was printed, `pause()` returned, and the rest of the program ran to completion.

---

If you want the process to send the signal *to itself* for some reason, you can do that too. The [`raise` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/raise.html) does that innately:

> The `raise()` function shall send the signal *sig* to the executing thread or process. If a signal handler is called, the raise() function shall not return until after the signal handler does.

So

```
raise(signum);
```

in place of `pause();` would work.

This isn't directly very useful here other than in the corner case of SIGKILL or other untrapable signals, which will have interesting results (try entering 9 and 19!). If you're exploring how signals and the process model work, though, it probably saves some time and effort fussing about to find the PIDs.

You could also [use `kill(getpid(), signum);`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) or `pthread_kill(pthread_self(), sig);` (which is defined to be exactly the same as `raise(signum)`).

Comment: You missed that `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.  (-: